# Why does this C++ program does not compile using modules?

Tags: c++, module

Sorry if i ask again about "moudules" in C++.
Im using g++ **gcc-c++-12.2.1-4.fc37.x86_64** in fedora 37 linux and vscode.
So i said: i will upgrade my knowladge with the book "A tour of C++ third edition" which its updated to c++20 standard.

The thing that the first program:

```
import std;
int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
}
```

Doesn't compile.
I have enabled "std=c++20" and "-fmodules-ts" and also tried "-std=gnu++20".

The output is this, its like the compiled modules are missing:

```
std: error: failed to read compiled module: No existe el fichero o el directorio
std: nota: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/std.gcm’
std: nota: imports must be built before being imported
std: error fatal: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
```

Ok it's in spanish becouse is my native tongue.
Any help?

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
import std;
```

This line of code requires not only module support, but also *Standard Library Modules* ([P2465R3 Standard Library Modules std and std.compat](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2465r3.pdf)) that's part of C++23.
From the [Compiler support for C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23) page on cppreference, we can see that it's still not supported by GCC libstdc++.

---

As OP mentioned that the code snippet is taken from Bjarne's book, I double-checked section 1.2 of it. In the paragraph after the next from the code snippet containing `import std;`, it's stated that this is not yet standard:

> The import directive is new in C++20 and presenting all of the standard library as a module std is not yet standard. [...]

Comment: "*it's clearly stated that this is not yet standard*" ... then why include it? "Hey, here's how to do something! BTW, it won't actually compile, but I'm still going to tell you how to do it." This is not an effective way to teach people the language.

Comment: @NicolBolas Immediately after that paragraph, there's a working version using `#include <iostream>` instead. I'm not sure whether this book is ideal for beginners, though.